# Run specific application on lower resolution?

Tags: kubuntu, wine, display-resolution

I am trying to run a game engine (LuaSTG-X) via wine, which, as you've probably guessed, is very slow.

So I want to lower the resolution for that window only (not changing the whole system's display settings)

Currently I have a 1920x1080 monitor, I want to make that game display as if it is run in a 800x600 one.

I wonder if that is possible?

System Information:

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-81-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: Have you exhausted the "Window Rules" settings in KDE System Settings?  Does the game itself not have settings that allow you to adjust the resolution?

Comment: It is a engine meant for development, so no. Window rules seem to only let me change sizes, etc.

Comment: Of course you have checked the wine site to see if this program is supported and what limitations it might have? https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1081

Comment: @David No results. It is actually a pretty new engine.